# What is the limit of $\frac{a + (n-1)d}{2a + 2(n-1)d}$ for $n \to \infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits

If $a$ and $d$ are constant, find $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a + (n-1)d}{2a + 2(n-1)d}$$

I tried letting $2a = A$ and $(n-1)d = B$ and assumes that it became zero but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Your limit has nothing to do with $x$. Is it $\lim_{n\to \infty}$?

Comment: Is it $x$ or $a$?

Comment: oh sorry, here, ill try and fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, isn't this pretty obvious you take 2 common from the denominator to get the same expression as the numerator. You cancel both the numerator and denominator to get the answer as 1/2.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a limit of a sequence ($n\in\mathbb{N}$?) 
If it isn't then you can note that both the numerator and denominator approach infinity. Apply l'Hospital's rule.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a+(n-1)d}{2a+2(n-1)d} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n}(a+(n-1)d)}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n}(2a+2(n-1)d)} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{d}{2d} = \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule (no 's' in the name) applies when numerator and denominator are differentiable *real-valued* functions. Sure, you could see, e.g. $a + (n-1) d$ as the real function $f(x) = a + (x - 1) d$ restricted to $\Bbb{N}$, but applying L'Hôpital's rule here like this is a bit of a conceptual error.

Comment: applies, provided that these are real valued functions, hence asking for clarification if it's a sequence. Thanks for pointing it out, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just Take 2 common from the denominator so that (a+(n-1)d) term gets Cancelled. Then the value of the function becomes 1/2.

Comment: @Nehorai Sure, the English could be improved, but this *does* answer the question.

Comment: @Gautam Jagdhish ok my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see where every part of you expression goes as $n\to \infty$?

When you have a sum of many terms, try to identify the one which is larger in the limit. Then try to collect it in the sum.

Answer (score 0):

The answer involves few theorems about limits.
I give you a verbose and complete answer.

1. Forget for a moment the operation of limit and analyze the term inside the limit,  $\frac{a+(n-1)d}{2a+2(n-1)d}$. Take out $(n-1)$ from the numerator and denominator (I'm assuming n > 1) $$\frac{a+(n-1)d}{2a+2(n-1)d} = \frac{(n-1) \cdot \left(\frac{a}{n-1}+d\right)}{(n-1) \cdot \left(\frac{2a}{n-1}+2d\right)} = \frac{\frac{a}{n-1}+d}{\frac{2a}{n-1}+2d} $$
2. Now, flashback and remember the limit, calculate it for $\frac{a+(n-1)d}{2a+2(n-1)d}$ or $\frac{\frac{a}{n-1}+d}{\frac{2a}{n-1}+2d}$ is the same because we've just proved the expressions are equal.
3. You note that the limit is in the form $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \: \: \text{with} \: \: f(n) := \frac{a}{n-1}+d \: \: \text{and} \: \: g(n) := \frac{2a}{n-1}+2d$$ There is a theorem for limits that states:

   T1. If $\lim_{n \to +\infty} f(n) = a$ and $\lim_{n \to +\infty} g(n) = b$ with $b \ne 0$ then $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{a}{b} = \frac{\lim_{n \to +\infty}f(n)}{\lim_{n \to +\infty}g(n)}$

   In plain English, **the limit of the quotient of two function is the quotient of the respective limits if they exist (and the one of the denominator function is not equal to zero)**.
4. So, let's try to see if the function limits exist so we satisfy the theorem hypothesis and can apply the theorem.

   4.1 We note that $\lim_{n \to +\infty}f(n)$ is in the form $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}k(n) + y(n)  \: \: \text{with} \: \: k(n) := \frac{a}{n-1} \: \: \text{and} \: \: y(n) := d$$ 
   Another theorem here,

   T2. If $\lim_{n \to +\infty} k(n) = l$ and $\lim_{n \to +\infty} y(n) = m$  then $\lim_{n \to +\infty}f(n) + g(n) = l+m = \lim_{n \to \infty}k(n)+\lim_{n \to \infty}y(n)$

   In plain English, **the limit of the sum of two function is the sum of the respective limits if they exist**.

   Rapidly you see that for this theorem the hypothesis are satisfied because the limits exist
   $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a}{n-1} = 0 $$
   $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} d = d $$
   So $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \left(\frac{a}{n-1} + d \right)= d$$

   4.2 You do the same steps I just did in 4.1 and you should get that
   $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \left(\frac{2a}{n-1} + 2d \right)= 2d$$

   At the end, you see that hypothesis of the first theorem (T.1) are satisfied so you can assert that
   $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{a+(n-1)d}{2a+2(n-1)d} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\frac{a}{n-1} + d}{\frac{2a}{n-1} + 2d } = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{d}{2d} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Anyway, it's overkill to do these steps (i.e. building a tree and apply theorems to return to the root) everytime you meet a limit of that type. You should do once to understand really what a limit is and how it deals with simple operations (sum,division,mult etc). In fact for this kind of limits a theorem exists :

T3. The limit 
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_1 n + a_2 n^2 + ... + a_k n^k}{b_1 n + b_2 n^2 + ... + b_l n^l} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^k a_i n^i}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^l b_j n^j}$$

is

- $0$ , if $l > k$
- $\pm\infty$ , if $l < k$ (\pm is the sign from the ratio of the first coefficients not equal to zero of the higher terms in n)
- $\frac{a_l}{b_l}$ , if $l = k$

Answer (score 0):

Note that for this equation there is no reason to bother with limits:

$\frac{a + (n-1)d}{2a + 2(n-1)d} = \frac{a + (n-1)d}{2(a + (n-1)d)} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{a + (n-1)d}{a + (n-1)d)} = \frac {1}{2}$

This is true, regardless of the value of a, n or d.